# Adding 84 inaccessible cardinals to ZFC can be inconsistent if...

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I found a mention in F. A. Muller's 2004 paper that adding 84 inaccessibles to ZFC makes the theory inconsistent if it is consistent with 17 ones, but adding instead 49 can be done consistently, although the resulting theory has no well-founded models. I find this intriguing. Is this true? If so, can someone give an intuitive sketch of a proof?

> *Muller, F. A.*, [**Deflating Skolem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11229-005-0800-0), Synthese 143, No. 3, 223-253 (2005). [ZBL1083.03015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1083.03015).

Comment: I have discovered he put the paper on his own webpage: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~mulle106/

Comment: Was expecting there to be some more context when I found the whole article, but nope... he just says that without any attribution. I certainly don’t know what he’s talking about. What is “17 ones”? If he means 17 inaccessibles then this certainly seems wrong. I would be also be interested if anyone could match this up to to a real fact cause it just seems like nonsense to me.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Maybe it *does* make sense, as the existence of seventeen $1$'s seems pretty inconsistent to me; consequently the consistency of such a claim implies *anything* by ex falso. Not sure how adding the number 49 improves the situation...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Per my answer, there is something true one can say which sounds *vaguely* like what the author's written and is nontrivial. But, oof, that paragraph ... did nobody referee that?

Answer (score 4):

**This is an utterly bizarre claim, and quite frankly gibberish as written. That said, there is an interesting nontrivial result which has vaguely the same "look," and may have been what the author intended (certainly it fits well into the claim being made in the article).**

---

First, while the paper is freely available [on the author's website](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Emulle106//Skolem-Synth2005.pdf), it's worth noting that the OP has gotten the claim *completely correctly*; a direct quote is

> Adding $84$ inaccessibles to ZFC makes the theory inconsistent if it is consistent with $17$ ones, but adding instead $49$ can be done consistently, although the resulting theory has no well-founded model.

**This seems thoroughly garbled to me**, and I suspect the author was just being careless here. The point they're making in this section is that there is a plethora of odd principles easily deduced from general metatheorems, and this is definitely true. But I can't parse what they've written.

---

The following is a precise and true statement; I suspect the author had something like this in mind. Let $T_k$ be the theory ZFC + "There are (at least) $k$ inaccessible cardinals." Then:

> $(*)_{17,49,84}:$ It is relatively consistent with $T_{49}+Con(T_{49})$ *(so in particular, possible so far as we know)* that:
>
> - $T_{17}$ has a transitive model,
> - $T_{49}$ is consistent but has no transitive model, and
> - $T_{84}$ is outright inconsistent.

*(And more generally for $k<m<n$ the analogous claim $(*)_{k,m,n}$ is true.)*

The proof of a claim like this is a combination of basic set-theoretic arguments and Godel's incompleteness theorem.

As a first step, note that by Godel's theorem if $T_k$ is consistent then so is $T_k+\neg Con(T_k)$. Meanwhile, for $k<n$ we have $T_n\vdash Con(T_k)$. Taking $k=49, n=84$ we get that if $T_{49}$ is consistent then so a fortiori is $T_{49}+\neg Con(T_{84})$.

---

*This next part is a bit technical:*

Of course, claims of the form $(*)_{a,b,c}$ above are more subtle. There we have *three* levels of consistency (transitive model, some model, no model), and this makes this more complicated; we need to do a bit more work.

If there is a model of $T_{49}+Con(T_{49})$, then there is a model of $$T_{49}+Con(T_{49})+\neg Con(T_{84}).$$ Let $M$ be such a model, and let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal (in the sense of $M$) such that $(L_\alpha)^M\models T_{18}$.

Let $N=(L_\alpha)^M$. $N$ and $M$ have the same natural numbers, so they agree about consistency statements. In particular, $N$ thinks that $T_{49}$ is consistent and $T_{84}$ is inconsistent. Meanwhile, $N$ also has a transitive model of $T_{17}$. But we because we "cut off" $M$ at the first point where we could get $18$ inaccessibles (this also uses the "minimality" of $L$), $N$ does not think that there is a transitive model of $T_{49}$.

So from a model of $T_{49}+Con(T_{49})$ we can build via incompleteness a model of $T_{49}+Con(T_{49})+\neg Con(T_{84})$, and in such a model an appropriate initial segment of the $L$ hierarchy will be in turn satisfy $T_{49}+Con(T_{49})+\neg Con(T_{84})+$ "$T_{49}$ has no transitive model" *(note that $T_{49}$ already proves that $T_{17}$ has a transitive model, so we don't need to add that separately)*.

---

As an aside, let me say a bit about the ordinal $\alpha$ above. I claim that $\alpha$ is countable. The countability of $\alpha$ is in fact a special case of a stronger fact:

> Let $T$ be *any* theory (in the language of set theory). Then if some level of $L$ satisfies $T$, the least such level is countable (that is, the least ordinal $\alpha_T$ such that $L_{\alpha_T}\models T$ is countable).

This is a consequence of the [**Lowenheim-Skolem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) and [**Condensation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_lemma) theorems:

- Suppose $L_\alpha\models T$. By the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem there is some countable $A\preccurlyeq L_\alpha$; this $A$ also satisfies $T$ (by elementarity).
- Let $B$ be the Mostowski collapse of $A$. Since $B$ is isomorphic to $A$ *(more precisely: $(A,\in\upharpoonright A)\cong (B,\in\upharpoonright B))$* we have $B\models T$.
- But by Condensation, $B=L_\gamma$ for some $\gamma$. Since $B$ is countable, $\gamma$ is also countable, and we're done.

*Note that this looks a lot like Skolem's paradox (that if ZFC has a model, it has a countable model). Indeed, this is really just a stronger version of Skolem's paradox in the more specific setting of ZFC + V=L.*

Comment: I think it may be good to emphasize that the author seems to be saying that if ZFC+"there are 49 inaccessible cardinals" is consistent but has no well-founded model, then ZFC+"there are 84 inaccessible cardinals" is inconsistent, and this is simply false.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Even that's a stretch for me - where does the "$17$" come in? It just reads as gibberish to me.

Comment: Yes, I suspect, as you said: The first assumption is that ZFC+"there are 17 inaccessible cardinals" has a transitive model. The second is that ZFC+"there are 49 inaccessible cardinals" is consistent but has no $\beta$-model. It is in the author's description of the conclusion that things collapse. Maybe he "meant" to say something about there not being a transitive model (or a $\beta$-model) of the 84 inaccessibles in a certain model living within one of the witnesses to the second claim, or something along those lines. Definitely gibberish as written.

Comment: Maybe he meant: If $T_{17}$ implies that there is no transitive model of $T_{49}$, then it also implies that $T_{84}$ is inconsistent.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Argh, you're right on both counts. I've deleted my incorrect comment and will fix my answer when I get the chance.

Comment: Why must α be much smaller than the 18th inaccessible in M? If M satisfies V=L (which I think is not ruled out by your construction), l(M)=m and alpha will be 18th inaccessible in M? [Earlier twice I think I posted the comment the wrong way. I hope this time I'm right. Getting used to this place.]

Comment: @MangeshPatwardhan I've edited my answer to explain this point. Basically: Lowenheim-Skolem (plus a bit more).

Comment: Yes, now I see what role incompleteness, downward lowenheim-skolem and minimality of L play.